# Add Hibernate interceptor to a session factory on run time

Tags: hibernate

I wish to add an interceptor to the session or the session factory on run time. 
I managed to do something like this with event handlers:

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventListenersRegisterer {
   /** The post load event listener. */
   @Resource
   private GenericPostLoadEventListener postLoadEventListener;

   /** The session factory. */
   @Resource
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


   /**
   * Register all event listeners.
   */
   @PostConstruct
   public void registerEventListeners() {
     EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry()
                    .getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

     registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_LOAD).appendListener(postLoadEventListener);

   }
}
```

I want to use an interceptor the same way... can I?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.  Instead:

Create an Interceptor or Listener yourself to be added permanently, but accessible by you to add/remove delegate Interceptors/ Listeners (or otherwise switchably enable/ or delegate your functionality).

Then, once you can get a reference to it at run-time (static singleton may be the easy way), you can programatically switch on/off your functionality or add/remove your delegates.

(I've actually done something related with Hibernate Generators, delegating according to deployed database type;  and it worked.)

Note:  the fly in the ointment here, is the configuration & startup;  initialization events won't be easily passed to delegates, which aren't created yet.

Comment: The code I published with event listeners at my question works well. The problem is that I need now an interceptor. I don't understand how you suggest to activate the interceptor.

Comment: Define your custom Interceptor, access it via a 'static singleton'  (simplest) or perhaps some kinda registry, then you can control it;  either by switching it on/off or adding/removing delegate Interceptors.

Comment: There are no ways to pass object references in via Hibernate configuration, so either it's gonna be a static reference -- MyInterceptor.getInstance() -- or your interceptor can register, and be found from, JNDI or whatever other registry you can make work.

Comment: Sorry... I still don't get your suggestion. I have an interceptor. fine. now, how do I connect it to the session factory? this is my question. It won't intercept anything if I don't connect it to the session somehow. I don't understand what is the connection between my question and static or singleton. I have an interceptor - it is spring managed as a singleton.

Comment: My suggestion is to connect your Interceptor to the SessionFactory at configuration time, then (having access via the static reference or whatever) to switch behaviour on/off or change the delegate Interceptors attached. WrapperInterceptor.getInstance().addDelegate( new MyActualLogic_Interceptor());